# Pod install gives error for not finding resources trying to install parse

Tags: ruby, parse-platform, cocoapods, apple-m1

I am getting the following error when I run `pod install` from the terminal in Rosetta 2 (M1 chip). The only pod I am trying to install right now is Parse.

It appears that it can't find certain resources with ruby. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
/bin/bash -c
set -e
ruby ParseUI/Scripts/convert_images.rb         ParseUI/Resources/Images/         ParseUI/Generated/PFResources

/Users/username/.asdf/shims/ruby: line 4: /usr/local/opt/asdf/bin/asdf: No such file or directory
/Users/username/.asdf/shims/ruby: line 4: exec: /usr/local/opt/asdf/bin/asdf: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your Podfile content so we can check it?
It seems to me (at this point) that your path looks strange:

`/usr/local/opt/asdf/bin/asdf: No such file or directory`

So, it is not finding that directory that (once again, seems at this point) you typed 'asdf' somewhere.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).